# Swift: Decodable

Tags: ios, swift

Lets say i have this json from an API request:

```
friends: {  
   "john":31,
   "mark":27,
   "lisa":17,
   "tom":41
}
```

I usually expect it in an array format:

```
friends: [  
   { "john":31 },
   { "mark":27 },
   { "lisa":17 },
   { "tom":41 }
]
```

But the API doesn't provide me this way the results. So i want finally to map it to an array of [Friend], where Friend is:

```
class Friend: Decodable {
  let name: String
  let age: Int
}
```

How should i serialize this json to get [Friend] ?

Comment: You should speak to whoever wrote your backend and tell them to change it. What were they thinking?

Comment: @AshleyMills yes, very true. While Maxim's answer will definitely work with this JSON format it is definitely not ideal :)

Comment: I can think of some cases when it's more efficient to pass large hash map over the web than to pass array which will be converted to hash anyway, but in this case I agree that array of objects is much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, example isn't valid json at all. To be valid it either shouldn't include "friends" label, or it should be embedded in another object like this

```
{
  "friends": {  
    "john":31,
    "mark":27,
    "lisa":17,
    "tom":41
  }
}
```

If I understand question correctly, you want to decode json object to swift array. I don't think there is a way to do so without writing custom decoding. Instead, you can decode json into `Dictionary` and when manually map it like so

```
struct Friend {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

struct Friends: Decodable {
    let friends: [String: Int]
}

let friends = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Friends.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    .friends
    .map { (name, age) in Friend(name: name, age: age) }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*: I recommend to change you API format to one like in [@scriptable's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52258148/6920962) (which was deleted while I was answering, hm), where `name` and `age` fields are properly defined. And where you're not limited to basically a pair of key-value to parse.

But if you can't or won't change it you may use something like this to decode your `Friend` type:

```
struct Friend: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let age: UInt

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let dictionary = try container.decode([String: UInt].self)

        guard dictionary.count == 1, let (name, age) = dictionary.first else {
            throw DecodingError.invalidFriendDictionary
        }

        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }

    enum DecodingError: Error {
        case invalidFriendDictionary
    }
}

struct Friends: Decodable {
   let friends: [Friend]
}

let friends = try JSONDecoder().decode(Friends.self, from: data)
```

It assumes `key` is `name` and `value` is `age`. And checks that there's only a one pair to parse.

Comment: I don't sure it will work with hash with more than one member. If you want to do custom decoding then you probably need to write decoder for `[Friend]`

Comment: @MaximKosov, I am sure that **it won't work** with Dictionary with more than one element, I put guard check exactly for this. Just like it was in original question where it was array of dictionaries with single key-value pair.